# Getting Files From Another User's Folder

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

So I've read the documentation for the dropbox api, and its quite rough around the edges, and Im not sure that I can do this. Basically what I want to do is make my app create a folder, give the user the link so that they can give it to other users. After those users have that link, they can paste it into the app and it will let them see whats in the folder. They don't even need to be able to see it, the app just needs to be able to download files from the folder. Its kinda exactly what a shared link would do in the normal dropbox. Is this at all possible? And if so, how would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

This certainly sounds possible, but you would probably need your own server-side component. The basic idea as I see it:

- user A links the app to their Dropbox account
- the app has the user pick a folder
- the app generates its own link for that folder and supplies it to user A
- user A supplies the link to user B
- user B supplies the link to the app
- the app looks up user A via the link, and uses [/metadata](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#metadata) or [/delta](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#delta) to list files from user A's account, and then [/files (GET)](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files-GET) to serve file content to user B (from user A's account).

The server-side component is important in order to avoid exposing user A's access token to any other user.

This would be much easier, and wouldn't require a server-side component, if Dropbox offered an API for Dropbox shared links themselves, since you could then just use [/shares](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#shares) to get one and pass that around directly. It doesn't though, so I'll pass this along as a request.

Comment: I couldn't quite figure out how to use those. I'm on iOS, do I just open these as links? Or do I make a request?

Comment: Those are just the general HTTP API endpoints. The specific methods you'll use will depend on which SDK/library you're using. tRefer to the the docs/header files/etc. for whichever you're using.